# SQL Server : show only first found result using WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to filter out Companies with US address, if the Company does not have an US address, show the GERMANY address instead, and if that does not exist, then any MEXICO address ... and if no such countries, show Empty cell.

Currently I have the following query

```
SELECT COMP.CompanyName, CNTR.Country, CNTR.Address 
FROM [dbo].CompaniesTable COMP
JOIN [dbo].CountriesTable CNTR on CNTR.accountid = COMP.accountid 
WHERE CNTR.Country = 'US' OR CNTR.Country = 'Germany' OR CNTR.Country = 'Mexico'
```

But my query shows US and GERMANY and MEXICO addresses.
I need only first found address.

I'm using SQL Server 2008

Thank you.

UPDATED: Added Schema

Comment: What's your Table schema ?

Comment: Please share what code you have written so far. In addition to the table schema, please also share some sample data as well as the desired output.

Comment: `top 1 ... where address in (...) order by case when address = ... then 1 else 0 end asc/desc`

Comment: Use a case statement in your where clause.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps calculate a rank based on the priority of a country.
Then filter on that.

```
SELECT CompanyName, Country, [Address]
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    COMP.accountid, COMP.CompanyName, CNTR.Country, COMP.[Address], 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY COMP.CompanyName
                       ORDER BY CASE CNTR.Country 
                                WHEN 'US' THEN 1 
                                WHEN 'Germany' THEN 2
                                WHEN 'Mexico' THEN 3
                                ELSE 9
                                END) AS rnk
  FROM [dbo].CompaniesTable COMP
  JOIN [dbo].CountriesTable CNTR on CNTR.accountid = COMP.accountid 
  WHERE CNTR.Country IN ('US','Germany','Mexico')
) q
WHERE rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "top". 
try this

```
SELECT top 1 COMP.CompanyName, CNTR.Country, CNTR.Address 
FROM [dbo].CompaniesTable COMP
JOIN [dbo].CountriesTable CNTR on CNTR.accountid = COMP.accountid 
WHERE CNTR.Country = 'US' OR CNTR.Country = 'Germany' OR CNTR.Country = 'Mexico'
```